# I am trying to do a show more/show less text button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a show more/show less button. The actual version is not very good because I just sliced while state is false and left it untouched while it is true. Right now I want to show just the first row in each card but I don't really know how.

```
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  const { name, text, firstButtonText, secondButtonText } = props;
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleReadMore = () => {
    setShow(prevShow => !prevShow);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={require(`../../assets/photos/${name}.png`)}
        title={name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography
          gutterBottom
          variant="h5"
          component="h2"
          className={classes.textStyling}
        >
          {show ? text : text.slice(0, 45)}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>

      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          {firstButtonText}
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={handleReadMore}>
          {secondButtonText}
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: Just use css for this, toggle a class, set the height of `Typography` to a single line, and work with `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional render the items you want, like this:

```
<CardContent>
{show &&(<Typography
  gutterBottom
  variant="h5"
  component="h2"
  className={classes.textStyling}
  >
    {text}
  </Typography>)}
</CardContent>
```

But then with your other rows.
Try conditional render the items you want, like this:

```
<CardContent>
  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2" className={classes.textStyling}>
    {text}
  </Typography>
  {show && (<div>...</div>)}
</CardContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to achieve this. Just set the line-height to the desired value, and max-height to multiples of that value you want to show.

```
.singleLine{ // 1 line
    line-height:1.5em;
    max-height:1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.multiLine{ // 3 lines
    line-height:1.5em;
    max-height:4.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

<Typography
      gutterBottom
      variant="h5"
      component="h2"
      className={show ? classes.multiLine : classes.singleLine}
    >
```

```css
.singleLine{ 
    width: 50px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    max-height:1.5em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.multiLine{ 
    width: 50px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    max-height:4.5em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
Single -------------------------
</div>
<div class="singleLine">
dasdasasdasdas dasdasdasdasd sadasd asdasd sadasd sadasd asdasd a
</div>
<div>
Multi -------------------------
</div>
<div class="multiLine">
dasdasasdasdas dasdasdasdasd sadasd asdasd sadasd sadasd asdasd a
</div>
```